# Google Sheets Sumif

Tags: google-sheets

Trying to use sumif to get total for column "E" based on Date (number) in column "C"

`=sumif(C1:C51,="AND(C1>=45047,C1<=45077)",E1:E51)`  creates error message "Formula parse error".

Column C1:C51 are dates formatted as MMM-DD rather than a number
(45047 - 45077 are May dates)
Column E is numeric values

Comment: please check if you copied the formula correctly, it contains a syntax error, and please also add the error message to your question

Comment: =sumif(C6:C51,="AND(C6>=45047,C6<=45077)",E6:E51)  Formula parse error

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a regular formula inside the `SUMIF` function. Only `>`, `>=`, `=`, `<>`, `<` or `<=` are working for numbers. Otherwise a text matcher with the wildcards `?` and `*` and some more rules is applied (see the docs for this, as it is irrelevant for your problem).

While the solution of @Mahmoud Khosravi might solve that exact problem, other conditions might not have such a simple arithmetic solution, so I would recommend that you add an extra column where you fill in the result of your formula `=AND(C1>=45047,C1<=45077)` e.g. in column F, pull it down over all your rows (1-51) and then simply use that column as criterion in the SUMIF: `= SUMIF(F1:F51,TRUE,E1:E51)`.

Also I would recommend for better readability of your data, that you either use the `DATE` function instead of numeric constants, or that you refer to two different cells where you also enter a date and format it like that, e.g. G1 for the min date and G2 for the max date. Your formula for each row would then be `=AND(C1>=$G$1, C1<=$G$2)`. You need the `$`s to prevent automatic index adjustment when you pull down your formula.

Comment: Excellent information, thank you.  Mahmoud's answer did solve the problem.  However your full explanation helps for future uses.  The Sheet in question actually has many columns containing data.  It is used to extract stock dividend payments by payment date.  I use separate cells as you suggested for conditional formatting that highlights the x-dividend and payment days.  Thank you for your assistance, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Conditional formatting would allow for "real" formulas in the condition, not just the limited forms of `SUMIF`, so there you probably don't need the extra columns ;)